# Developing NuGet packages without pushing to NuGet server

Tags: c#, nuget, package, nuget-package

I have 2 solutions in VS.

The first one is for packages.

```
Packages.sln
 - PackageA
 - PackageB
 - Package..
```

Each packages has `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` to generate Package.nupkg.

And solution with services where I'm going to use that packages

```
Services.sln
 - ServiceA
 - ServiceB
 - Service..
```

The question is how can I during development change package and use it in service?

I've tried this:

- Create Local NuGet source in some folder "artifacts"
- Each package has it in .csproj

:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="GenerateNuspec" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec Command="nuget.exe push bin\Debug\*.nupkg  -Source &quot;Local Package source&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

- Then I need to change version of package, let's say `<VersionPrefix>1.0.1</VersionPrefix>`
- Then in service change to `<PackageReference Include="PackageA" Version="1.0.*" />`

So, make change in package, build, remove package from nugget cache, rebuild service, test, if ok then commit and CI will push it to nuget server. There are many steps to test package. Please suggest what workflow should I use when I develop packages and want to test it before pushing to Nuget server.

Comment: you could create a private nuget feed and push your packages there, and your test projects can source them from there. You can either get a private feed server (lots of ways, you can google) or use a simple file share as the repository (slow but easy to set up)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, thanks. But in that case after each build I need change version. push to private nuget, change version in service, pull nugget, use. I know how to create a private feed server. I ask about better workflow

Comment: well that's how nuget works. If you want to test a new version of a package, you upgrade the version in your project. Are you asking whether it's possible to manually override the package content without an upgrade? I'd say that's potentially quite tricky depending on the package content etc.